# Proccessing a php result JSON with arrays

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

I want to proccess this JSON result: `["13:00:00","14:00:00"]` in my mobile application, java language.
The Json might be more than 2 item, or less. Maximum 8 item, 8 hour.
I make a php request in my application, send the datas wich make a query run, the result is in the json result. 
Here is my code:

```
try {
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend)); //post the datas for the query
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jArr = jObject.getJSONArray("dates");

    if (jObject.length() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++)
        {
            String[] dates = jArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("dates");
            /*Here i don't really have idea what to do
              I want a String array which indexes are the result hours
              like dates[0] = "13:00:00"*/
        }
```

And the php:

```
$place = $_POST["place"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$sql = "SELECT appointment FROM dates WHERE place = '$place' AND appointment LIKE '%$date%' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$datehours = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    array_push($datehours, $row["appointment"]); //after it datehours like  [0] => 2016-04-08 13:00:00
}
$dates = array();
foreach($datehours as $x => $x_value) {
    $muvelet = explode(" ",$x_value); //here I select from the timeststamp only the hours
    array_push($dates, $muvelet[1]); //$date like [0] => 13:00:00
}
echo json_encode($dates, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //the encode is ["13:00:00","14:00:00"]
```

**So how should I proccess this json encode?** Should I write somehow else in the php? Unfortunately the encode with numeric array isn't a pair like an assoc array (`$date["firsthour"] => 13:00:00` in this case the json something like `["firsthour" : "13:00:00"]` if I know right, and here I can identify the elements.

Comment: Use JSONArray instead of JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you receive the response you can use

```
       JsonArray mArray = new JsonArray(<Your response string>);
```

After that you can iterate through the array as you would a normal array. You can process data as it is, you dont have to change in php.

Comment: Okay @Ragesh so it should be fine?
`HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(result);

 if (jArr.length() != 0) {
     for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++)
     {
            dates[i] = jArr.getString(i);
     }`

Comment: Yes it should work. Try it out and let me know if you run into any trouble, So i can help.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your json like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0;i<0;i++){
String yourDate = jsonArr.optString(i);
Log.v("Data",yourDate);
}
```